# Content Porter Webdav Error

Tags: content-porter-2009, webdav

While importing package via CP2009 in our 2011 environment I am getting a "WebDAV URL is invalid" error. I am importing a single component (default component template) with all dependent content disabled, save 'content' and 'structure'.

I am trying to find out why CP isn't working that's why I am exporting and importing to the same environment..

This is the webdav url of the component I am trying to import export (it's not localized).

```
\\productie.domain.nl\webdav\Internet SSO-ICT Handleidingen\Componenten\Content\010_Nieuws\Test nieuwsbericht 1.xml"
```

CP log is showing:

9-4-2013 9:17:02    [Information]   Starting new Import process with ID 76e0ffbe561c43278209eda2edfd4e43
4/9/2013 9:17:03 AM [Information]   Resolving item mappings
4/9/2013 9:17:03 AM [Information]   Mappings resolving started
4/9/2013 9:17:03 AM [Verbose]   Executing request: http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI'>
    

    

4/9/2013 9:17:03 AM [Verbose]   Executing request: http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI'>
    

    

4/9/2013 9:17:04 AM [Information]   Mappings resolving finished
4/9/2013 9:17:04 AM [Verbose]   Closing package: 
4/9/2013 9:17:04 AM [Error] WebDAV URL is invalid
4/9/2013 9:17:04 AM [Information]   Import completed

And fiddler is showing this:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
2   401 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   341     text/html; charset=us-ascii cp:7420 
3   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   455 private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 cp:7420 
4   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/UploadPackage.aspx 0   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    cp:7420 
5   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/UploadPackage.aspx?processId=76e0ffbe561c43278209eda2edfd4e43  227 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    cp:7420 
6   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   423 private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 cp:7420 
7   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   394 private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 cp:7420 
8   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   1.495   private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 cp:7420 
9   200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/DownloadFile.aspx  1.524   private     text/plain  cp:7420 
10  401 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   341     text/html; charset=us-ascii cp:7420 
11  200 HTTP    ontwikkel.tridion.ourdomain.nl  /ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx   334 private, max-age=0      text/xml; charset=utf-8 cp:7420
```

Mapping xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tcccp:Mappings version="3.0" xmlns:tcccp="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.2/ImportExport">
<tcccp:ItemSet role="Category">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Doelgroepen" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Domeinen" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Informatietypen" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Overzichtlijsttype" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Taal" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="Component">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Content/010_Nieuws" exportTitle="Test%20nieuwsbericht%201.xml" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Content/Afbeeldingen" exportTitle="Logo%20Rijksoverheid.png" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Content/Afbeeldingen" exportTitle="Titelbalk%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen.png" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="ComponentTemplate">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Default%20Component%20Template.tcts" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="Folder">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" exportTitle="Componenten" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten" exportTitle="Content" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Content" exportTitle="010_Nieuws" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Content" exportTitle="Afbeeldingen" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten" exportTitle="Systeem" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Schema%27s" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="GEN" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="GSA" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="Configuratie" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Overheidsmedia" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Template%20building%20blocks" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="MultimediaType">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="AVI%20video.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Bitmap%20image.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="CSV%20bestand.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Encapsulated%20PostScript.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Excel%20sheet.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Executable.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Flash%20file.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Gif%20image.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Jpeg%20image.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Mobile%20video.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Mp3%20music.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Mpeg%20video.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="MSAccess%20database.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Ondertitels.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Pdf%20document.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Plain%20text.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Png%20image.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Postscript.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Powerpoint%20presentation.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="QuickTime%20movie.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Real%20player.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Rich%20text.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Sit.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Sound%20file.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="True%20Type%20Font.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Windows%20Media%20Video.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Word%20document.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/" exportTitle="Zip.tmt" importContext="/" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="PageTemplate">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Default%20Page%20Template.tpts" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="Publication">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="" exportTitle="Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="Schema">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="abc.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="afbeelding.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="AlineaCompact.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="AlineaStandaard.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="contactformulier.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Contentblok.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="CustomCode.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Download.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="FolderStructuregroupInfo.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GEN" exportTitle="GEN%20configuratie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="GeneriekeEmailNotificatie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Google%20Analytics.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="CollectieKoppeling.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA/Configuratie" exportTitle="GSA%20Configuratie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA/Configuratie" exportTitle="Overzichtlijsttype%20configuratie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="GSACollectieLijst.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="Overzichtlijst%20GSA.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="RssFeed.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="RssMap.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/GSA" exportTitle="Zoekformulier%20filter.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Hyperlink.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="IGZ%20rapport.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="kamerstuk.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="kamerstukken.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="letter.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="LinkLijst.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="nieuwsbericht.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/Overheidsmedia" exportTitle="Overheidsaudio%202%2E0%20-%20eigen%20bestanden.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/Overheidsmedia" exportTitle="Overheidsvideo%202%2E0%20-%20eigen%20video.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/Overheidsmedia" exportTitle="Overheidsvideo%202%2E0.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Overzichtlijst%20IS.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Poll.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Publicatie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Publication%20properties.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="PublicationConfiguration.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Rapportenlijst%20IGZ.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="RSSFeed%20IS.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="SiteStat.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="standaard_pagina.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Toespraak.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="uitgelicht.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="WebConfig%20Connectionstring%20Config.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="Weblog.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s" exportTitle="ZoekenConfiguratie.xsd" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<tcccp:ItemSet role="TemplateBuildingBlock">
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem" exportTitle="Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Template%20building%20blocks" exportTitle="Constanten.tbbs" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Template%20building%20blocks" exportTitle="Generic%20functions.tbbs" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="/Internet%20SSO-ICT%20Handleidingen/Componenten/Systeem/Template%20building%20blocks" exportTitle="SiteEdit.tbbs" importContext="" importTitle=""/>
</tcccp:ItemSet>
<!-- Add a URI element for each URI you want to replace, e.g:
<tcccp:URIReplacements><tcccp:URI source="tcm:69-735" destination="tcm:118-882" /><tcccp:URI source="tcm:69-231" destination="/webdav/Publication/Building%20Blocks/MyComponent.xml" /></tcccp:URIReplacements>-->
</tcccp:Mappings>
```

XML of component in package

```
<tcccp:Item xmlns:tcccp="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.2/ImportExport">
    <tcccp:BlueprintParentUrl/>
    <tcccp:PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl/>
    <tcccp:BinaryFileLocation/>
    <tcm:Data xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
<tcm:Title>Redirect</tcm:Title>
<tcm:Type>Normal</tcm:Type>
<tcm:Schema IsMandatory="false" xlink:href="/webdav/[website]/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/Redirect.xsd" xlink:title="Redirect" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
<tcm:Content>
    <Content xmlns="uuid:7063F0B1-CBD5-4C2A-8F61-BAD7879F7BEA">
<url>/actueel/nieuws</url>
    </Content>
</tcm:Content>
<tcm:Metadata/>
<tcm:ApprovalStatus xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" xlink:title="Undefined" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
<tcm:IsBasedOnTridionWebSchema>true</tcm:IsBasedOnTridionWebSchema>
<tcm:MultimediaType xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" xlink:title="" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
    </tcm:Data>
    <tcccp:Dependencies>
<tcccp:Dependency dependencyType="Publication" itemType="Publication" itemUrl="/webdav/[website]" mandatory="true" xpath=""/>
<tcccp:Dependency dependencyType="OrganizationalItemFolder" itemType="Folder" itemUrl="/webdav/[website]/Componenten/Content/010_Actueel" mandatory="true" xpath=""/>
<tcccp:Dependency dependencyType="Schema" itemType="Schema" itemUrl="/webdav/[website]/Componenten/Systeem/Schema%27s/Redirect.xsd" mandatory="true" xpath="tcm:Data/tcm:Schema/@xlink:href"/>
<tcccp:Dependency dependencyType="ApprovalStatus" itemType="ApprovalStatus" itemUrl="tcm:0-0-0" mandatory="true" xpath="tcm:Data/tcm:ApprovalStatus/@xlink:href"/>
    </tcccp:Dependencies>
</tcccp:Item>
```

XML above is another trial import/export using the most simple component available

Kind regards
Ryan.

Comment: I have a feeling the key issue here might be that you are: "importing content with all dependent content disabled". Could you elaborate a bit more on what the Component contains (does it contain links or Keyword fields for example)? and you mention you are importing it into the same environment you exported it from, should I see that as a sort of backup/restore or are you importing with a different import context (in a different publication)?

Comment: Just tried it with full dependent content on export and import but still same issue.

Comment: yes your mapping file and also clarify a bit more what you are actually doing, are you indeed trying to move content or is it something else?

Comment: Can you post the webdavurl of the component you're trying to export/import?

Comment: Is it the localized Component?

Comment: This is the webdav url I am trying to export and import. It's a non localized component.

\\productie.domain.nl\webdav\Internet SSO-ICT Handleidingen\Componenten\Content\010_Nieuws\Test nieuwsbericht 1.xml. |

And I am not trying to move anything. Just an export/import of the same component. So no updates or anything. Just getting CP to show that it's working.

Comment: Could be that your Component contains invalid XML, export will work, import will fail. Try with a different Component, preferably one you just created and know is correct. But could also mean something else is broken.

Comment: Indeed, post a component XML. It might be that not the component itself is broken, but it has some link to item that no longer exist

Comment: I have added the component XML available in the package to my post but it's very straightforward.

Comment: Can you rename the component to something simple without spaces? It might be just a URL encoding issue.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular instance it was a problem with a user in Tridion having a name containing a slash '/'. It threw off webdav.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've seen issues with item paths with slashes, wouldn't have thought to check the user as well.